# Problem in accessing wsdl from URL(http) from bpel

Tags: http, wsdl, bpel, urn, apache-ode

HI,
I want to access wsdl file that is imported in bpel definition, can i do that or i will have to create local copy and then use it?
Because whenever it run the process it gives me this:

```
FATAL - GeronimoLog.fatal(116) | openResource: invalid scheme (should be urn:)  http://localhost:9090/axis2/services/Inverse?wsdl
```

I am using ODE engine.

thx

---

AL

Answer (score 1):

Especially with Apache ODE you need to create a local copy of the WSDL. This also makes sense IMO, since your BPEL process is bound to this particular WSDL and by maintaining a local copy you avoid unpredictable results that may occur when the remote WSDL changes for some reason while the process instance is still running. I guess you wouldn't like to implement a Java class that inherits from a Java interface that might be changed at a remote location and thus breaks your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You need a local copy of the WSDL along with the BPEL File. In the WSDL File you should define PartnerLink Types and in the BPEL File you have to define partner link of those partnerlink types. Then you can access it.